# My App needs login , how app store testers will know it

Tags: iphone

I have created an app in which user need to login to proceed , they can get their login id and password from my website.

Now when I am trying to upload my app to Apple Store , how should I give them my website's url so that they can create a login id to check my app or how should I give them some test user id and password with which they can login and test the app.

Seriously I googled it and found it nowhere . Please answer as my app is ready but can't upload it without this information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a test account for them, and put the username and password in the **Review Notes** field when you enter the app information in iTunes Connect.
[image]

Comment: Also leave a pre-created account.

Comment: Great thanks , stackoverflow always helps